# Date won't display

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to display a simple php date function in a HTML table, but when I run the page it just displays the actual code in the table.

```
    <?php
echo"
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
            </td>
            <td>Rectangle 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 3</td>
            <td>Rectangle 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 5</td>
            <td>Rectangle 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 7</td>
            <td>Rectangle 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 9</td>
            <td>Rectangle 10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you save the file as `.php`. I think you save the file as `.html`. It should be `.php` extension.

Comment: You are not closing the `"` on yout code. Just before `echo`ing the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You didn't need an echo first also date() is not an HTML function its an PHP function.

```
<?php
echo"<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>".
date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A"). "
</td>
<td>Rectangle 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rectangle 3</td>
<td>Rectangle 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rectangle 5</td>
<td>Rectangle 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rectangle 7</td>
<td>Rectangle 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rectangle 9</td>
<td>Rectangle 10</td>
</tr>
</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am assuming you have a server that runs php setup.

If you have a mac checkout http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/ for installing and running apache with php on your mac. This is a good article on the basics.

Here is a very minimal working sample: But please copy and save as some-file-name.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');?>

<head>
<title>Php Dates</title>
</head>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?></td>
    <td>Rectangle 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rectangle 3</td>
    <td>Rectangle 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rectangle 5</td>
    <td>Rectangle 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rectangle 7</td>
    <td>Rectangle 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rectangle 9</td>
    <td>Rectangle 10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Obviously, there is much more you can do with Dates and PHP so checkout :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your code like this.

```
<?php
    echo"
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."
            </td>
            <td>Rectangle 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 3</td>
            <td>Rectangle 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 5</td>
            <td>Rectangle 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 7</td>
            <td>Rectangle 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rectangle 9</td>
            <td>Rectangle 10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
?>
```

Otherwise you have to use like this

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');?>
        </td>
        <td>Rectangle 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rectangle 3</td>
        <td>Rectangle 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rectangle 5</td>
        <td>Rectangle 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rectangle 7</td>
        <td>Rectangle 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rectangle 9</td>
        <td>Rectangle 10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```